# angularjs inheritance objectprototype may only be an object or null

Tags: angularjs

I thought this would be a simple base and child class task but this error is throwing me.

I created a base class like this:

```
module A.B.C {

   export class instructionBase {

      constructor(
      var1: class1,
      var2: class2,
      ...etc for 10 injected classes) { //init code }

      method1(){}

      method2(){}
   }
}
```

My inherited class is like this:

```
namespace A.B.C {

   export class instructionComponent extends instructionBase {

      static $inject = ["", "", ""...for 10 times]

      constructor(
         var1: class1,
         etc for 10 times) {

         super(var1, for 10 times)
         }
   }

   // Register the component
   angular.module("myApp.abc")
    .component("instructioncomponent", {
        templateUrl: "/.../instruction.component.html",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        transclude: true,
        controller: instructionComponent 
    });

}
```

At run time I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
>       at setPrototypeOf ()
>       at __extends (someOtherClassICreatedALongTimeAgo.js:6)
>       at instrumentComponent.ts:4
>       at A.B.C (instrumentComponent.ts:4)
>       at A.B.A.B(instrumentComponent.ts:45)
>       at A (instrumentComponent.ts:45)
>       at instrumentComponent.ts:45

What's interesting to me is that on line 6 of the error the namespace repeats twice partially. DO I have an unintended circular reference?

Looking at this class (someOtherClassICreatedALongTimeAgo) from the error it also extends a base class so I must have wires crossed somewhere.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Most likely at the time you try to extend `instructionBase` it is `undefined`. That would be my guess. If you want to be sure about this try putting it in a same file

Comment: This was a useful diagnostic tip. The ultimate solution was that I had forgotten to add my base class to bundle config so yeah...it was undefined.